# The return code of an application is an int16_t?

Tags: c++, c, operating-system

When talking about starting a new process, you can do it using `int system(char* command)`. If you pass an **non NULL** parameter, you can get:

- `-1` if the child process cannot be started;
- a return code of the child process otherwise;

> note: in Unix/Linux the return code is located **on the higher eight bits of the result, while the lower eight bits contain the termination reason code**>{1}<, so a retcode equal to 1 will be returned as 256; you can get the actual return code by shifting the value eight bits to the right; there is also a macro named WEXITSTATUS() that does it for you.

Searching for [the implementation](https://unix.superglobalmegacorp.com/Net2/newsrc/sys/wait.h.html) of `WEXITSTATUS()` it's a shift 8 bits to the right.

`#define WEXITSTATUS(x) (_W_INT(x) >> 8)`

This is the reason why I tend to think that return codes are 2 bytes (and also from >{1}<). The quote is from a C course found online.

P.s I would like to know the difference between the return code and termination reason code, aren't they the same?

Comment: For what operating system? Something POSIX compliant?

Comment: I would like to know for both windows and unix like. For example, compiling with cygwin (posix compatible) on windows (target being all platforms: max, win, linux) I still need to shift the value 8 bits to the right

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu _"I would like to know for both windows and unix like"_ That's exactly the problem. Windows supports negative exit does (DWORD's essentially), while Unix / Linux doesn't.

Comment: "C course found online". Exercise caution with these things. `int system(char* command)` runs an executable program, not a "C/C++ application" (whatever that could mean). The return code does not depend on the language(s) used to write said program.

Comment: Termination reason code: Did the process exit on its own, or was it killed by a signal? In the latter case, it doesn't have a return code for hopefully obvious reasons, but you *can* find out what signal was responsible, and if a core dump was made.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ , DWORD is unsigned in windows, meaning it can still not have negative values. Or I did [read wrong](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/262627d8-3418-4627-9218-4ffe110850b2)?

Comment: That code you found is ancient and comes with major code smell. I suspect it was likely written for some MC68000 flavour with 16 bit data bus. Also notably, MC68k were exclusively Big Endian. The question kind of belongs on the retro-computing site, since this is dinosaur stuff.

Comment: Where is that quote in your question from?

Comment: @Shawn *Did the process exit on its own, or was it killed by a signal? In the latter case, it doesn't have a return code for hopefully obvious reasons,* [It certainly does](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08): "The exit status of a command that terminated because it received a signal shall be reported as greater than 128."  The exit status of a process killed by a signal is usually 128 + the signal number.

Comment: You should use the macros defined by `#include <sys/wait.h>` to extract information from the status rather than doing the bit shifting by your own code. The exit code extracted by `WEXITSTATUS(x)` is only valid if `WIFEXITED(x)` is non-zero. Similarly, `WTERMSIG(x)` is only valid if `WIFSIGNALED(x)` is non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

There s different reasons for termination:

- process terminates calling `return` (explicitly or not)
- process terminates after signal delivery
- process stopped after signal delivery. This one is not really termination but need to be caught in many situations.

For **each** of theses terminations a code is accessible, respectively:

- value returned (only low eight bits of it)
- signal number
- signal number

Comment: Per POSIX, the status will be "greater than 128" for processes killed by a signal.  It's usually 128 + signal number.

Comment: @AndrewHenle right, but using predefined functions/macros is better than decoding values by yourself.